# How can I use extract values using 2 keys using AWK in Bash?

Tags: awk

I want to use a Bash script to make summarize reading csv file.
The script only reads $1, $2 and $4.

I want to use $1, $2 as a key and
$4 for value but if there is a records for "critical"
then print **it as $1, $2, "critical" in a row.**
but instead of using "==", "=~" is not working on awk.
and "contains" is not working properly in this time.

If anyone helps me to solve this problem, it would really be appreciated.

'''

**Input**

```
A, SVC-ID01, Critical
A, SVC-ID01, Info
A, SVC-ID01, Good
A, SVC-ID01, Good
A, SVC-ID01, Good
A, SVC-ID02, Info
A, SVC-ID02, Info
A, SVC-ID02, Good
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
B, SVC-ID-04, Good
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
```

```
awk -F "," '{ 
if (NR != 1) 

arr[$1","$2];
arr2[$1","$2]=$4;

if (arr2[$1","$2] == "Critical")
{
    arr2[$1","$2]="Critical";
}
else if (arr2[$1","$2] == "Info")
{
    arr2[$1","$2]="Info";
}
else
{
    arr2[$1","$2]="Good";
}
}  END {for (i in arr) {print i "" arr[i] "," arr2[i]} }'  ${filename} | sort $2
```

**output**

```
A, SVC-ID01, Critical
A, SVC-ID02, Info
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
```

'''

Comment: `awk` in `bash` does not make any sense. Awk is a binary on its own and has made its way through multiple shells over time and it is generally not dependent on the shell flavor for its working.

Comment: @Inian NOOOO, I was so near the golden bash badge! :D

Comment: @JamesBrown: Am sure you'll get it within this week. Border ones are OK, but this has no relevance to the shell at all

Comment: @Inian Sure man. Makes it way more worthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a couple of lookup tables to make "Critical" the "max" value:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = SUBSEP = OFS = ", "
        state["Good"] = 1;     lookup[1] = "Good"
        state["Info"] = 2;     lookup[2] = "Info"
        state["Critical"] = 3; lookup[3] = "Critical"
    }
    value[$1, $2] < state[$3] {value[$1, $2] = state[$3]}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in value) print key, lookup[value[key]]
    }
' Input
```

This outputs

```
A, SVC-ID01, Critical
A, SVC-ID02, Info
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have 4 columns and if not `Critical` or `Info` is already set, assign `$3` to the array. The field separator also looks like it should be `", "` or else you'd need to match on `" Critial"` and `" Info"`.

Example:

```
awk -F ", " '{
    arr[$1", "$2];
    if ($3 == "Critical" || arr2[$1", "$2] == "Critical")
    {
        arr2[$1", "$2]="Critical"; 
    }
    else if (arr2[$1", "$2] != "Info")
    {
        arr2[$1", "$2]=$3;
    }
}
END {for (i in arr) {print i "" arr[i] ", " arr2[i]} }' ${filename} | sort $2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
$3=="Critical" || $3=="Info" && a[$1 OFS $2]!="Critical" || a[$1 OFS $2]=="" {
    a[$1 OFS $2]=$3
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file
```

Output:

```
B, SVC-ID-03, Good
B, SVC-ID-04, Info
A, SVC-ID01, Critical
A, SVC-ID02, Info
```

The output appears random, you can control that by piping the output to `sort`. If the data is pre-sorted like in the sample, you could use the following and skip the `sort`:

```
$ awk '{
    if($1 OFS $2!=p && FNR>1) {
        print p,b
        b=""
    }
    if(b==""||$3=="Critical"||$3=="Info"&&b!="Critical"||b=="")
        b=$3
    p=$1 OFS $2
}
END {
    print $1,$2,b
}' file
```

Comment: @shellter Oh yeah, there was a typo which I only apparently fixed to one place. Thanks for the heads up!